# Access violation with lockless queue in multithreaded app

Tags: c++, multithreading, access-violation, lockless

I wrote a simple lockless queue based off of the principles outlined in the msdn article below, and from the DXUT lock free pipe code also below:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee418650(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://code.google.com/p/bullet/source/browse/trunk/Demos/DX11ClothDemo/DXUT/Optional/DXUTLockFreePipe.h?r=2127

So, I have a producer/consumer model setup where my main thread feeds rendering instructions, and an rendering thread consumes available messages and issues the corresponding opengl calls.  Things work fine if I sleep my main thread each loop/iteration for a sufficient amount of time, but if I don't sleep it long enough (or not at all), I get an access violation exception:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00b28d9c in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00004104.
Unhandled exception at 0x777715ee in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00004104.
```

My call stack is:

```
ntdll.dll!777715ee()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
ntdll.dll!777715ee()    
ntdll.dll!7776015e()    
Engine.exe!RingBuffer<2048>::BeginRead(void * & ppMem=, unsigned long & BytesAvailable=)  Line 52 + 0x10 bytes  C++
Engine.exe!Thread::ThreadMain(void * lpParam=0x00107d94)  Line 41 + 0xf bytes   C++
```

I can't quite figure out what the problem might be.  The Code for my lockless queue is below:

```
    template <uint32 BufferSize>
    class RingBuffer
    {
    public:
        RingBuffer()
            : m_ReadOffset(0)
            , m_WriteOffset(0)
        {}
        ~RingBuffer()
        {}

        bool Empty() const
        {
            return (m_WriteOffset == m_ReadOffset);
        }

        void BeginRead(void*& ppMem, uint32& BytesAvailable)
        {
            const uint32 ReadOffset = m_ReadOffset;
            const uint32 WriteOffset = m_WriteOffset;

            AppReadWriteBarrier();

            const uint32 Slack =    (WriteOffset > ReadOffset) ?
                            (WriteOffset - ReadOffset) :
                            (ReadOffset > WriteOffset) ?
                                (c_BufferSize - ReadOffset) :
                                (0);

            ppMem = (m_Buffer + ReadOffset);
            BytesAvailable = Slack;
        }

        void EndRead(const uint32 BytesRead)
        {       
            uint32 ReadOffset = m_ReadOffset;

            AppReadWriteBarrier();

            ReadOffset += BytesRead;
            ReadOffset %= c_BufferSize;

            m_ReadOffset = ReadOffset;
        }

        void BeginWrite(void*& ppMem, uint32& BytesAvailable)
        {
            const uint32 ReadOffset = m_ReadOffset;
            const uint32 WriteOffset = m_WriteOffset;

            AppReadWriteBarrier();

            const uint32 Slack =    (WriteOffset > ReadOffset || WriteOffset == ReadOffset) ?
                            (c_BufferSize - WriteOffset) :
                            (ReadOffset - WriteOffset);

            ppMem = (m_Buffer + WriteOffset);
            BytesAvailable = Slack;
        }

        void EndWrite(const uint32 BytesWritten)
        {
            uint32 WriteOffset = m_WriteOffset;

            AppReadWriteBarrier();

            WriteOffset += BytesWritten;
            WriteOffset %= c_BufferSize;

            m_WriteOffset = WriteOffset;
        }

    private:
        const static uint32 c_BufferSize = NEXT_POWER_OF_2(BufferSize);
        const static uint32 c_SizeMask = c_BufferSize - 1;

    private:
        byte8 m_Buffer[ c_BufferSize ];
        volatile ALIGNMENT(4) uint32 m_ReadOffset;
        volatile ALIGNMENT(4) uint32 m_WriteOffset;
    };
```

I'm having difficulty debugging it as the read/write offsets and buffer pointer look fine from the watch window.  Unfortunately, when the app breaks, I can't watch autos/local variables from the BeginRead function.  If anyone has experience working with lockless programming, any help on this problem or advice in general would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Just as an observation, your data structure doesn't seem to contain any atomic variables or atomic operations - how is this going to work?

Comment: I was under the impression that read/writes to m_ReadOffset and m_WriteOffset would be atomic given the alignment and their size.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @programmer It's not necessarily the case that reads and writes would be consistent between CPUs.

Comment: Hm, that's fishy. Even if reads and writes were atomic, you're making no attempt to verify that the structure is still in the correct state when you write the update. I believe something like an atomic compare-and-swap would be an inevitable part of a concurrent container.

Comment: Was there something wrong with the standardized types such as `uint32_t`?

Comment: Is this a single producer/single consumer queue, or are there more than one of either?

Comment: Yes, only one thread writes (main), and only one thread reads (rendering).

Comment: I think there is a bug in `BeginWrite` that will allow client code to write enough stuff in the buffer such that `Empty` will return true.

Answer (score 2):

You might find these articles of some interest...

[Lock-Free Code: A False Sense of Security](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/210600279)
  [Writing Lock-Free Code: A Corrected Queue](http://drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/210604448)

In the first article Herb Sutter discusses another author's implementation of a lock-free queue and points out some of the things that can go wrong.  In the second article Herb shows some corrections to the original implementation.

As a learning exercise, trying to build your own lock-free queue is a pretty good idea.  But for production work you'd probably be safer finding a pre-existing implementation from a reliable source and using that.  For example, the [Concurrency Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504870.aspx) offers the [concurrent_queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355358.aspx) class

Answer (score 1):

You haven't any memory fences.  Access to volatile variables are only ordered with respect to each other, not to other operations.

In C++0x, you'll be able to use `std::atomic<T>` to get the appropriate fences.  Until then you'll need OS-specific threading APIs, such as Win32 `InterlockedExchange`, or a wrapper library such as boost::thread.

Ok, I see that `AppReadWriteBarrier` is supposed to provide a memory fence.  How's it implemented?

Comment: The function `AppReadWriteBarrier` is a wrapper on win32 for _ReadWriteBarrier, which serves as a memory fence I believe?

Comment: @programmer: You'd think so, but the MSDN page makes it sound weaker.  What compiler version are you using?

Comment: @Programmer: Pay special attention to the caution on top of the [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20w0x5e.aspx).

Comment: Oh, I missed that part of the doc!  I'm using Visual Studio 2008, v 9.0.21022.8

Comment: Hmmm.  The documentation here says that VS 2005 uses `lfence`/`sfence` for volatile access on SSE2 in any case (not 100% sure if this applies to VS 2008): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686355(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @programmer: MS now keeps multiple versions of the documentation.   That's good when they change behavior, but unfortunately bugs only get fixed in the most recent version.  So sometimes reading the newest one gives you more information about an older compiler.

Comment: @msandiford: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/19/10155452.aspx.  Yes, VC2005 does provide memory fences for `volatile` access.  But this code is designed for fences at additional sequence points, which it isn't getting.